# Can an action to an optgroup label be detected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to detect when my user clicks on the optgroup label so that I can add and remove the options in the group.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: But is that possible to click the `optgroup` label? In fact, there are no cross browser solutions to capture click events on the dropdown list (show up part, not an element).

Comment: Best of my knowledge, no.  I've not been able to get a click event on one.

Answer (score 2):

I have just tested onclick event on optgroup label and this is the result:

Firefox (latest) - WORKS
Opera (latest) - WORKS
IE 9 - WORKS
Chrome (latest) - FAIL

Here is the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/44at2/2/